# my Custom TagHelpers Not Working in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I followed a few guides on creating a `custom tag helper` for `ASP Core`.

I Have two `tag helpers` in one `namespace` :

```
namespace Forum.Core.TagHelpers
{

    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Condition))]
    public class ConditionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool Condition { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!Condition)
            {
                output.SuppressOutput();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And

```
namespace Forum.Core.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Permission))]
    class RolePermissionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool Permission { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.SuppressOutput();
        }

    }
}
```

And I Add dependencies into

> _ViewImports.cshtml

`@addTagHelper` *, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

`@addTagHelper` *, `Forum.Core`

But I can only use **Condition** in my pages !

[True style of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgiCJ.png)

[MyProblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULkt6.png)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: how can you know it isn't working when you have it set to suppress output?

Comment: @JoeAudette , The work of this Tag Helper is exactly suppressing, but with condition .but, I did not write the condition

Comment: you have Permission defined as boolean but "string" is not a boolean value

Comment: @JoeAudette, I am sorry :) ,In the Permission, a conditional statement is placed.But,My problem is not changing the color of the tag when I call the Permission, inverse of Condition

Comment: Your `RolePermissionTagHelper` class needs to be `public` (it's `internal` by default).

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Thank you very much for your advice, I did not have enough care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your Permissiontaghelper is not public. Try this:

```
namespace Forum.Core.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Permission))]
    public class RolePermissionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool Permission { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.SuppressOutput();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In `_ViewImports.cshtml` you need add only root namespace

```
@addTagHelper *, Forum
```